# How can I change the color font of the inspection description in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, settings, preference

I want to change the font color of 'Required type' and 'Provided' in IntelliJ but I can't find the way.

[image: 1]

Searching on Google...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this color directly without using a theme plugin.
That color is controlled by the `Label.infoForeground` attribute in the theme plugin. See here for details: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-customize.html

You only can report this issue to this theme plugin author to improve the color here or fork that theme plugin, change the `Label.infoForeground` for it.